# How do i stop data from resubmitting when reloaded on Flask?

Tags: flask

When the page is reloaded, the data is resubmitted into the `notes[]` list, and is then printed out as shown in the html code. How do I prevent a POST request to happen on a reload, instead have GET run?

```
 app=Flask(__name__)
 notes=[]
 @app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
 def index():
      if request.method == "POST":
         note = request.form.get("note")
         notes.append(note)
         return render_template("index.html", notes=notes)
      else:
         return render_template("index.html")
```

on html

```
  <form action="{{url_for('index')}}" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="text" name="note" placeholder="insert note">
  <button>submit</button>

  </form>
  <ul>
 {%for note in notes%}
 <li>{{note}}</li>
  {%endfor%}
  </ul>
```

What is the issue and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - you cannot stop a browser from resubmitting a form.

For Flask, this is just another post request coming in.

How should Flask decide whether a request was intentional and which not?

The only thing which comes to my mind is... that you create a unique token for your form, for each time it is loaded, and then you check this in your Python code.

More info about here:
https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html